# Looking for algorithm to find n unset bits in a bitset

Tags: c, algorithm

Background:
I'm writing a physical memory allocator which allocates 4KiB chunks. It uses a bitset to mark which 4KiB chunks of memory have been used. I do not have a standard C library available to me.

Question:
I'm looking for an algorithm which will find n consecutive unset bits, in the smallest gap such that I can leave the largest gaps of unset bits available.

Example:
Let's say a bitset contains the following bits:

```
 0010 0000 0111 0001 1100 0011
```

If I want to set 4 bits, the algorithm should return bit number 18.

Comment: btw, do you aim at solving coalescing when freeing the memory?

Comment: Please add an example (preferably an illustrated one).

Comment: precisely, if you just want to search for the most suitable consecutive bits, the easiest way is to scan through all bits and the performance depends on the implementation details. but if you have additional requirement of breaking coalescing problem into pieces, you may have to take other strategies instead of this one you are heading for.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to deal with memory fragmentation, does the memory ever get deallocated? The reason HuStmpHrrr and I are interested in this aspect of it is that you can get a fairly easy implementation if no deallocation is used but it's a lot more tricky if you have to reallocate memory.

Comment: I've added an example of what I'm looking for. I believe coalescing should solve itself when freeing memory as the bits will be unset, and the algorithm should be able to find the most suitable consecutive bits. Either way, I'm not looking to explicitly solve coalescing.

Comment: Do you actually really need it to be this general? In my experience, it's enough to be able to find 2MB contiguous blocks. With only two different sizes (effectively 1 and 512), fragmentation is easier to solve.

Comment: Some of these [bits hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this in 2 passes:

**Pass #1:**
Scan the array, noting the number of consecutive zero-bits, and the start of those bits.

From your example, the scan would produce:

```
2 bits, starting at 0
6 bits, starting at 3
3 bits, starting at 12
4 bits, starting at 18
```

**Pass #2:**
Scan the data from pass #1, looking for the target value (4), or the smallest value larger than the target.

Both passes seem trivial to write in C, and this should be a general solution to work in all cases.

After you get this working, I also see some optimizations so that you may never have to run Pass #2 at all in certain cases.

Comment: As you say, you don't need the second pass: if on the first pass you find a block with exactly n bits, you can stop there and use it immediately, and if you don't, you can keep track of the location of the smallest block seen so far, and choose that after the first pass completes.

Comment: I've found this answer most helpful in writing my own implementation. I'll post my code in the question when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

as i mentioned in my comment, things go totally different when you are trying to deal with coalescing. but to solve the problem you are asking now. it's pretty easy by using `Red Black Tree`, which i am used to call `RBTree`.

there are thousands of `RBTree` implementation out there so you can choose one to fit in your language. where i provide my way to `allocate` memory only using python-like pseudocode. (as i said, if you try to figure things out when freeing the memory, it's a different problem.)

RBTree:

key: the number of 0's.

value: the first position of consecutive 0's.

so in your case, you problem should be initialized as:

```
rbt=new RBTree()
rbt.insert(2, 0)
rbt.insert(6, 3)
rbt.insert(3, 12)
rbt.insert(4, 18)
```

forgive me if i count wrong.

the when you want to allocate a chunk of memory:

```
func alloc(num_of_chunks):
    # try to find the key-value-pair that is the min one that satisfy: chunk.key >= num_of_chunks
    chunk=rbt.find_ceil(num_of_chunks) 
    if chunk is Nil: raise NotFound
    ret=chunk.value
    # may locate some chunks that have bigger size than required.
    if chunk.key>num_of_chunks:
        rbt.insert(chunk.key-num_of_chunks, chunk.value+num_of_chunks)
    return ret
```

so to maintain the tree.

**Advantage** of using RBTree:

1. it's fast. the linear search i propose in the comment is `O(n)`, but using RBTree, it shrinks to `O(lg n)`, which means it's more scalable.
2. easy to maintain. there are thousands of well-implemented libraries out there to fit your different requirements.
3. if you use RBTree by tracking the position of the chunk(ie. the `value` field in my code), you will have good track on the memory you allocated and could give good result when you try to solve coalescing.

---

**Update**

this answer seems to involve dynamic memory allocation, which may introduce hen and egg problem, which actually is not true.

if you know a chunk is not allocated, it has to be unused. therefore, data of RBTree could be stored in the unused chunk, which means metadata actually is spread over memory space. so in C, a node in such problem could be:

```
struct node {
    int length; // key
    struct node *left, *right;
}
```

in the very first bytes in the chunk.

so what you have to do is to remember the `root`.

```
struct node *root;
// your code should operate on rootp, since rotation on RBTree may have root changed.
// all interfaces related should all receive struct node ** type.
struct node **rootp = &root;
```

"so what about the value? you didn't define a field to store the address of the chunk."

yes, i have defined. since the data itself is stored in the chunk, so the address of `struct node` is the address of chunk.

so in such a way, you can avoid dynamic memory allocation, and, well, it seems i am not answering how you could find a suitable sequence of bits already... but i think in this way, you could manage your memory allocation better.

Comment: I like this solution. Sadly it's not suitable - constructing an RBTree would require allocating memory, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @NFSGamer i've update my answer explaining how you can avoid allocating memory.

Comment: I'm gonna keep this answer on hand for future reference, as I still want to implement the bit set. However next time I write a memory allocator, I'll be sure to try this method first!

Answer (score 0):

```
int find_free(int alloca_mem, int req)
{
    int min_len = INT_MAX;
    int start = 0;
    int min_len_index = -1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_BITS; ++i)
        if (alloca_mem & (1 << i)) {
            int len = start - i;
            if (len > req && len < min_len) {
                min_len_index = i;
                min_len = len;
            }
            start = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return men_len_index;
 }
```

Comment: `alloca_mem | (1 << i)` is always true.  I think you mean `alloca_mem & (1 << i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Call the size of a machine word w (often w = 32 or 64), and the total number of 4KB memory pages m.  If there are g gaps between already-allocated blocks, and there is some free length-n block that fits entirely within a machine word (and you are happy with choosing a smallest such block, rather than one that straddles a boundary between two words), then it can be found in **O(m/w + g) time** by exploiting the way **carries in integer addition "ripple":**

1. Given a bitmap word representing w 4KB pages, invert all its bits.  Now any block consisting of k consecutive free 4KB pages is a block of k consecutive 1-bits.
2. If you add an integer whose only 1-bit is the LSB of this block, the carries will ripple all the way left, setting all k bits in this block to 0 and the next bit to 1.

Using just this it's not too hard to find a gap that contains n unset bits in O(m/w + g) time without using expensive or "strange" instructions like multiplications, divisions or bit scans.  But in order to find the *smallest* such block, you seem to need either bit scans or divisions.  Luckily we can limit the number of times we need to use these instructions to at most w-1 operations in total across the entire bitmap, since that is the largest number of times that the currently best gap can be "shrunk" to a smaller one.  (Instead of using divisions, you could use code similar to the last paragraph to find the index of the MSB in O(log w) time using simpler instructions; this may be faster, but the point is moot, since so few divisions are needed.)  We still need O(g) multiplications, which is perhaps not ideal, but these are fast on modern CPUs.

```
const int m = /* HOW MANY BLOCKS */;
const int w = sizeof (unsigned) * CHAR_BIT;
unsigned bits[m / w];

unsigned findSmallestBlock(unsigned n) {
    if (n > w) return UINT_MAX;    // Can only find within-word blocks.
    unsigned bestI = UINT_MAX;    // Index with bits[]
    unsigned bestLsb = 0;  // Has a 1-bit in the LSB of the gap; 0 = "no solution"
    unsigned bestShifted = ~0;    // The gap's bits, "flush right".
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof bits / sizeof bits[0]; ++i) {
        // Find the shortest block in bits[i], if one exists
        // First, handle an edge case
        if (bestLsb == 0 && bits[i] == 0) {
            // We don't handle this edge case
            bestI = i;
            bestLsb = 1;
            bestShifted = ~0;
            if (n == w) break;    // Perfectly snug
        }
        unsigned y = ~bits[i];
        unsigned probe = y & (y - 1);    // The LSB of the gap we will test
        while (probe << (n - 1)) {    // Left-shifting it too far => 0 => stop.
            y += probe;    // Ripple!
            unsigned edge = y & (y - 1);    // Extract new LSB.  Overflow to 0 OK.
            unsigned gap = edge - probe;    // Every bit in the gap is 1.
            // Is the gap big enough?
            if (probe << (n - 1) <= gap) {
                // The gap is big enough.  Is it the tightest fit so far?
                // Doing this with bit-scan operations is easy; without them we can
                // use integer multiplication and division, but we want to keep the
                // divisions to a minimum.  Needs an edge case to be handled above.
                if (gap < bestShifted * probe) {
                    // Found a new, shorter gap.
                    // The division shifts the entire block right so that it starts
                    // at bit 0.  It's expensive, but happens at most w-1 times.
                    bestI = i;
                    bestLsb = probe;
                    bestShifted = gap / probe;
                    // Is it perfectly snug?  If so, we can stop now.
                    if (probe << (n - 1) > gap >> 1) goto done;    // Yes, "goto".
                }
            }
            y -= edge;            // Clear the *new* LSB; ignore intervening bits
            probe = edge << 1;    // Again, skip over all intervening bits
        }
    }

done:
    if (bestLsb == 0) return UINT_MAX;    // Didn't find anything

    // Find the index of the 1-bit in bestLsb in O(log w) time.
    unsigned pos = bestI * w;
    unsigned z = w >> 1;    // The number of bits we will try to shift right
    while (bestLsb > 1) {
        unsigned x = bestLsb >> z;
        if (x) {
            bestLsb = x;
            pos += z;
        }
        z >>= 1;
    }

    return pos;
}
```

A word on the time complexity: O(m/w + g) is the same as the O(m) time some other solutions propose when g is around the same size as m, which can happen: e.g. if every second 4KB page was allocated then g = m/2.  But if g is small -- whether because not many pages have been allocated, or because nearly all of them have, or because they have simply been allocated and deallocated in a pattern that leads to few gaps appearing -- then the time complexity is much closer to O(m/w).

One more thing: Without changing the time complexity, this code can be adapted to look for blocks that straddle word boundaries by keeping track of the final gap in each word, and doing a one-off test at the start of each word to see whether growing the previous word's final gap will work.  Looking for blocks larger than w is also possible (aside: any gap that satisfies a request for n > kw pages must contain at least k full-word 0 values in bits[] -- using this could drop the constant factor a lot when searching for large gaps).  Both of these extensions just require more bookkeeping.